# My Chrome installation is old, but I can't upgrade or purge it. Why?

Tags: apt, upgrade, google-chrome

Since my upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 both my Firefox and my Chromium installations are snap packages. This means that [installing Gnome extensions is not possible](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741074) through either of those browsers anymore. I then checked the google-chrome browser which I installed a long time ago, but that just crashes. I went to the command line to investigate:

```
$ which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome

$ sudo apt search google-chrome
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
google-chrome-stable/now 78.0.3904.70-1 amd64 [installed,local]
  The web browser from Google

$ sudo apt purge google-chrome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome

$ sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (78.0.3904.70-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
```

As you can see it's a very very old version (78) of Chrome (released in 2019). I tried both upgrading and purging it, both both fail.

So what do I do next? Manually remove it (something like `sudo rm /usr/bin/google-chrome && sudo rm /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`)? Any other idea?

Comment: use `sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable` and then check the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`. It should contain something like `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`. Then `sudo apt update && apt-cache show google-chrome-stable`

Comment: you can use dpkg --list to find the chrome package and purge the same. if you want to install the latest version of chrome, you can download the same from chrome website and open the same with ubuntu software app to install.